# Extract matching substrings in two lists

Tags: python, string

If I have two lists of strings (where both lists contains the same number of elements), such as the following:

`A = ["abc-foo", "abc-bar", "abc-oof", "abc-huh"]`

`B = ["cde-foo", "cde-bar", "cde-oof", "cde-huh"]`

How can I get a list that contains the matching strings across elements?

`C = ["foo", "bar", "oof", "huh"]`

Edit: modified example. In general, I will not know how long the non-matching parts of the strings will be. I will also not know how they are delimited.

I have taken a look at using intersections, but if I'm not mistaken, this only works if the entire string is the same in both lists.

Comment: `foo1` matches with `abcfoo` in `foo` only. 
`foo2` matches with `xyzfoo2` in `foo2`. Is that clearer?
The comparison is made across the elements in each list. I.e. element 1 in list `A` vs element 1 in list `B`, and so on. I guess I should also clarify that I'm looking for the largest such match.

Comment: is there an application for this?

Comment: so we can assume the dashes arent arbitrary?

Comment: @Ironkey arbitrary in what sense? they could be underscores, slashes, backslashes. The point is that the first part of the string in each list will be different across lists, but they will share the latter part.

Comment: arbitrary as in will there be a nonalphabetical separator between substrings?

Comment: in your example, taking just the part after `-` from either list works. Give us a few examples where this is not the case

Comment: also are we matching each element in the 1st list to all other elements of the 2nd list or just those of the same index...

Comment: Is this what you want? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem (but then multiple times, of course)

Comment: Ah, sorry for not clarifying. I see what you mean but in my case, the suffix at some point will match completely, not partly.

Comment: @Ironkey I'm trying to match just the elements in the same index

Comment: do you know *anything* about what might delimit substrings, such as if it might be non-alphanumeric (or even better non-alphabetic)

Comment: I'm wondering if it can be done without knowing this. However, for the sake of simplicity, assume there is a non-alphabetic delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
A = ["abc-foo", "abc-bar", "abc-foo2", "abc-bar2"]

B = ["cde-foo", "cde-bar", "cde-foo2", "cde-bar2"]

print([i for x,y in zip(A,B) for i in x.split([i for i in x if not i.isalpha()][0]) if i in y])
```

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foo2', 'bar2']
```

Comment: Please take a look at the example again. I just edited it. Unfortunately I won't always know what the separator will be.

Comment: well if we knew anything about the delimiter this could possibly work, maybe you could code something up so you *do* know what the delimiter will be

Comment: @Ironkey thanks for the answer. I was trying to see if without knowing anything about the delimiter this could be possible, i.e. it could be a letter as well. But for the sake of simplicity, let's say the delimiter is a non-alphabetic character.

Comment: let me work on that then, sorry for the delay in response